# GPS timestamp help. Android device synchronization fails in unity3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gps, timestamp

I've encountered a problem, and need help to figure out what's happening. The idea is to synchronize 2 or more android devices with respect to a GPS location timestamp. I've heard that GPS time is very accurate, unlike system time, which may vary across few seconds. However the results I get are not what I expected.

```
 void Start() {
     Input.location.Start ();
     double UTC_timestamp = Input.location.lastData.timestamp;
     Input.location.Stop ();  
 }
```

So in this case, UTC_timestamp represents the total number of seconds since January 1st 1970, 00:00:00.

But if I request a timestamp on 2 different devices, I am getting quite a sure difference, and my attempts to synchronize them via satellite's timestamp fails.

Here is how I tested that:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using System.Collections;

 public class GPSTime: MonoBehaviour {
     double UTC_timestamp;
     public Text txt_UTC;
     IEnumerator Start() {
         UTC_timestamp = getGPSTime ();

         while (Application.isPlaying) {
             yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
             UTC_timestamp ++;
         }
     }

     void Update() {
         print("UTC: "+ UTC_timestamp);
         txt_UTC.text = "UTC: " + UTC_timestamp;
     }

     private double getGPSTime() {
         Input.location.Start ();
         UTC_timestamp = Input.location.lastData.timestamp;
         Input.location.Stop ();
         return UTC_timestamp;
     }
 }
```

I run this on two different devices, and the timestamp I am getting differs quite significantly:

So out of three app launches I get the following:

```
         DEVICE 1
```

1) 1438782375.605

2) 1438782610.260

3) 1438782681.926

4) 1438782960.266

```
         DEVICE 2
```

1) 1438782505.306

2) 1438782680.011

3) 1438782675.226

4) 1438782967.400

So first launch differs by ~130 seconds!!! Second trial differs by ~70 seconds, and third trial differs by 6-7 seconds. Fourth trial differs by around 7 seconds.

Why such strange differences? What can I do to get the best results possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that I have found my answer after all. In case anyone else is facing these issues, here is what I found out.

```
 Input.location.Start (); //initializer, takes two arguments
```

Default arguments are:

```
Input.location.Start (10, 10);
```

both are of type float, first is accuracy (10 meters) and the second is how much the device has to be displaced to request a pulse from the satellite, (10 meters). So the reason to why I was getting such strange numbers for timestamp on both devices, is that I did not consider that I actually had to move, for the time to get updated. So what I did is I decreased the accuracy to 100 meters (I do not need such high accuracy for getting a timestamp, as 10 meters) and set the displacement value to zero, and I got perfects PPS (pulse per second) where both devices were in sync, which is exactly what I needed.

Another point to make, gps signals don't get through very well if you are indoors. Much depends on whether the sky is open and how tall the buildings are around you. That factors in as well, in case you are experiencing some gps fix troubles in this context. However I can confirm that GPS time is very accurate indeed, and works very well on unity engine on android devices. iOS not tested yet.